# calculating derivative using values and mask in CPP

Tags: c++

I got set of values and based on those values using mask I want to calculate derivative for every value. where mask is as:

```
mask[9] = {-d,-c,-b,-a,0,a,b,c,d};
```

values are as(of course there are numbers in mask instead of letters but to make it easier to understand concept itself):

```
pointX[128] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...}
```

So derivative for example for `deriv_pointX = 4` should be calculated as:

```
0*(-d)+1*(-c)+2*(-b)+3*(-a)+4*0+5*a+6*b+7*c+8*d
```

(EDIT: i might not been clear enought, formula is as, choose for which pointX you want to calculate derivative and multiplay it by "0" from that point take 4 neibour numbers from left of it and 4 from right and multiple them with corresponding neibour numbers from "0" from mask[], all add together to get result for pointX. So choosen pointX is always multiplied by "0")

example2:
deriv_pointX[5] = 1*(-d)+2*(-c)+3*(-b)+4*(-a)+5*0+6*a+7*b+8*c+9*d

My current code does not work:

```
void calculate_deriv(int pointX[128], int mask[9])
{
    int deriv_pointX[128];
    for(int i=4; i<128; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            deriv_pointX[i]=pointX[i]*mask[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose your derive_pointX array you've shown Is actually pointX .Isn't it ?

Comment: @AbhishekPanjabi - yes thats is correct I've already corrected it. thanks.

Comment: Also give an example for deriv_pointX =5. So that your process can be understood. If I'm mistaken in answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you omitted the first 4 points because you cannot compute them. That's good, but you forgot to ignore the last 4 points as well (you can't compute them either).

You also forgot to reflect that in the formula used to compute `deriv_pointX[i]`, the first element in the sum is `pointX[i-4]*mask[0]`, then comes `pointX[i-3]*mask[1]` and so on... Too see that, just let i = 4 in the previous formulaes and you'll see the first terms of your example.

Your for loop would become something like this:

```
for (int i=4; i < 124; ++i) {
    deriv_pointX[i] = 0; // Just to assert that we start our sum from 0
    for (int j=0; j < 8; ++j) {
        deriv_pointX[i] += pointX[i-4+j]*mask[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this "-4" do? i understand it would be for i = 0 -> 0-4+0 = -4

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line in code with this :

```
deriv_pointX[i]+=pointX[j]*mask[j];
```

What you were doing was overwriting value of multiplication every time. You've to do addition of all the multiplications .
And I've used shorthand notation a+=b which means a=a+b.
Also you've to take inner for variable with pointX as you want 0 then 1 and 2 and so on . If you use outer for variable then it's value won't change , also it's value can go out of scope .
One more thing to take care is you've to initialize values of array otherwise garbage values will be there and you may see surprising results.